# CSS style like Windows Seven/Vista

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, styles

I need to create a web application using ASP.NET MVC, jQuery and web standards for a customer with a style which look like Windows Vista/Seven.

Can anybody indicate me a link to do this with CSS? I have searched on the web, but I couldn't find it. I'd like to have interface elements like "window", "menu", "buttons", "form controls", etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This might be a question for doctype.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try these links:

- [Windows 7 Emulation with CSS3 and jQuery](http://webstandard.kulando.de/post/2010/03/23/windows-7-fenster-mit-css3-und-jquery-tutorial-teil-1)
- [Create Windows 7 start menu using CSS3 only](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2010/04/06/windows-7-start-menu-css3.aspx)

Comment: Both of these links are dead

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you are limited to ASP.NEt MVC or not, but here are some ASP.NET AJAX controls. All of these controls have Vista themes and also some bonus Windows 7 themes. They look identical to the real thing and the controls all use jQuery too!

<strike>Here is the live demo of the [Windows 7 / Vista themed ASP.NET controls](http://demo.componentone.com/ASPNET/ControlExplorer/C1Window/VisualStyles.aspx)</strike> (link broken)